# SMTP send email works offline but not online

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, email, smtpclient

i have a simple contact page on my private homepage.

Offline it works perfectly, online nothing happens.

Any idea?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        btnSend.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "changeIMG('" + btnSend.ClientID + "', 'Images/Senden_Hover.jpg');");
        btnSend.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "changeIMG('" + btnSend.ClientID + "', 'Images/Senden.jpg')");
    }
}

protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNachricht.Text))
    {
        SendEmailUserContact(txtAbsender.Text, txtNachricht.Text);
        Response.Redirect("~/Contact_suc.aspx", false);
    }
}

public static void SendEmailUserContact(string betreff, string nachricht)
{
    SendEmail(betreff, nachricht, "von@exampl.com", "an@example.com");
}

private static void SendEmail(string betreff, string nachricht, string von, string an)
{
        ///Zambuu
        string strSmtpServer = "smtp.example.com";
        string strUser = "kontakt@example.com";
        string strPasswort = "xxx";

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(von);
        mail.To.Add(an);
        mail.From = from;
        mail.Subject = betreff;
        mail.Body = nachricht;

        string host = strSmtpServer;
        int port = 25;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(host, port);

        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(strUser, strPasswort);
        client.Credentials = nc;

        client.Send(mail);        
}
```

Comment: No one, it just happens nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the SMTP have approve the sender. So the machine that hosts the online contact page, is a different machine than the one you are developing on. You have to give access on the mailserver on the machine that hosts the page.

Comment: I don't get it... The mailserver is a mailserver hosted by a web hoster who hosted my domain.

Comment: Can you read some logs on the mailserver and see if its trying to send the mail? My guess is that it's trying but is being rejected